# Custom fonts working on development but not in production django

Tags: css, django, django-templates, digital-ocean

I have a project I'm working on that's hosted on Digital Ocean's app platform.
In development my locally stored fonts work just fine. As soon as I load my project on Digital Ocean they no longer work.
I use Digital Ocean's spaces for static files and uploaded files.

My CSS looks like this:

```
/* Fonts */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'canto';
    src: url('../fonts/Canto-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    src: url('../fonts/Poppins-Light.woff2') format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'canto-roman';
    src: url('../fonts/Canto-Roman.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'poppins-bold';
    src: url('../fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

I've also tested:

```
/* Fonts */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'canto';
    src: url('/static/fonts/Canto-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

This also works fine in development but not in production.
My folder structure looks like this:

```
-Project
--app
--app
--templates
--media
--static
---static/CSS -> .CSS file
---static/fonts/ font files
```

All other files work fine, just the fonts don't.
I've tested this with two seperate computers. Neither one has the fonts installed.
Did I miss something?

edit:
I've also added CORS configuration to my spaced bucket to see if that fixes the issue. No luck.

edit2:
The console gives me this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () Canto-Bold.woff2:1
```

So for some reason the server will not let me load the fonts. Anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Are you using AWS to host your static files? I had to upload my fonts manually to make it work once.

Comment: @PhilM I’m using Digital Oceans Spaces for storing files. I acces it with django-storages which is based on AWS

Comment: Sorry I forgot to check if you replied and realised I could have given you the full answer instead of just asking you if we are using AWS. Glad you found the solution by yourself!

Comment: @PhilM No worries, you pushed me in the right direction. Its a better way to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work by manually selecting the font files in my Spaces bucket and setting their permission to public.
Not the most ideal solution but it works.